# Pointer to local variable in AT&T ASM

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm writing an assembly program (using `as` to asemble) using `libc` (specifically `scanf`) and from my experience `scanf` is used like this:

```c
int x;
scanf("%d", &x)
```

I can call `scanf` and push the arguments all fine:

```
pushl -4(%ebp)
pushl $msg_template
call scanf
```

As you can see, the `x` in my C code above is `-4(%ebp)` because it is a local variable.

The thing is, like stated above `scanf` takes `&x`, not just `x`.

I've tried both `(-4(%ebp))` and `$-4(%ebp)` and both, as expected, fail.

How can I accomplish `&x` with `-4(%ebp)`?

Comment: You need to use `lea -4(%ebp), %eax; push %eax` or an equivalent sequence to get the address. PS: you can ask a compiler locally or using godbolt.org

Comment: Same way a compiler will; look at `gcc -m32` AT&T output on https://godbolt.org/